# What is the scope of object expression when it's declared on top level of source or package?

Tags: oop, object, kotlin, scope

I'm learning about *object* in **Kotlin**. I can't realize what is the scope of the object that is declared outside a class.
For example:

> 

```
val point= object {
            public var x: Int = 0
            var y: Int = 0
        }
```

Situation that i examined (and didn't come to any conclusions):

1. When I declare it outside a class, then try to use it inside a function, then point is valid but the members x and y aren't recognized.
2. When I declare it outside a class, then try to use it as a member of a class, it isn't recognized there at all.
3. When I declare it outside a class (public of course), then try to use it from another source file it isn't recognized.

Can someone help me to understand the scope of object expression?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: @IR42, thanks but the question came after i have already read this link (completely)

Comment: Note that this would work if you write `object point {...}` rather than `val point = object { ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` in this case creates an object of anonymous class (the same as `object: Any`).

From docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

> Note that anonymous objects can be **used as *types* only in local and private** declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type of a **public function or the type of a public property**, the actual type of that function or property will be the declared **supertype of the anonymous object, or Any** if you didn't declare any supertype. Members added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.

`point` is a public static variable, so the actual type of this variable is `Any`

Comment: but i gave it a name : point. Is it still anonymous? Also why doesn't the editor complaining that i wrote it out of a local scope?

Comment: @Eitanos30 anonymous object means an object of anonymous **class**, `point` is the name of the variable (reference), that refers to the object

Comment: when you say: *"only in local and private declarations" *, the word local mean to function or it can be something else? and also why editor doesn't complain that object can't be declared outside of a class?

Comment: local means in methods, lambdas, constructors, init blocks. "why editor doesn't complain that object can't be declared outside of a class" because it's valid declaration. `can be used as types only in local and private` means that actual type of the variable will be the type of anonymous class and you will be able to access the members declared inside the anonymous class

Comment: but i just now, wrote a code, with private object (anonymous) outside of the class (package or source scope), and function in the file can reach to all the members i defined inside the object. So how it goes with the local demand?

Comment: @Eitanos30 "local **and private** declarations"

Comment: doesn't it mean it have to be both?

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared in a file outside of any class are declared directly in the package.

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#packages) (**objects** emphasis mine):

> Functions, properties and classes, **objects** and interfaces can be
> declared on the "top-level", i.e. directly inside a package:
>
> ```
> // file name: example.kt
> package foo
>
> fun baz() { ... }
> class Bar { ... }
> ```
>
> - If you do not specify any visibility modifier, `public` is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible
>   everywhere;
> - If you mark a declaration `private`, it will only be visible inside the file containing the declaration;
> - If you mark it `internal`, it is visible everywhere in the same [module](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules);
> - `protected` is not available for top-level declarations.
>
> Note: to use a visible top-level declaration from another package, you
> should still [import](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports) it.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> // file name: example.kt
> package foo
>
> private fun foo() { ... } // visible inside example.kt
>
> public var bar: Int = 5 // property is visible everywhere
>     private set         // setter is visible only in example.kt
>
> internal val baz = 6    // visible inside the same module
> ```

And [also from the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

> Note that anonymous objects can be used as types only in local and
> private declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type
> of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type
> of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the
> anonymous object, or `Any` if you didn't declare any supertype.
> Members added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.
>
> ```
> class C {
>
>     // Private function, so the return type is the anonymous object type
>     private fun foo() = object {
>         val x: String = "x"
>     }
>
>     // Public function, so the return type is Any
>     fun publicFoo() = object {
>         val x: String = "x"
>     }
>
>     fun bar() {
>         val x1 = foo().x        // Works
>         val x2 = publicFoo().x  // ERROR: Unresolved reference 'x'
>     }
> }
> ```

So when you do

```
val point= object {
    public var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
}
```

You are creating a `public` object of type `Any` in the *package*. Because the type is of `Any`, it's not possible to lookup the properties of your anonymous object you defined. However, if you make the object `private`, you can use it:

```
private val point= object {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
}

val x = point.x
val y = point.y
fun editPoint() {
    point.x = 1
    point.y = 2
}
```

Comment: who needs to be private? The class who returns the object or also the object itself where it defined? In the top example you made the function to be private..
in the lower you made the object as private

Comment: The object needs to be private where it is declared. The top example and lower example are explaining different things. The top example is explaining how top level objects work. The lower example is explaining how public/private objects work. "I" didn't write it, they are direct quotes of the documentation. I wrote the final two code blocks to demonstrate how to use that information to solve your problem.